# Entire DB get duplicated after saving records

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

hi i am using SQL server 2014
and i am using ef6
and mvc5
every time i try to save an order entire db gets duplicated please help
order controller is as follow
i looked at jquery.unobtrusive-ajax i think it is been used one
and there are no return partialview in project

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{

    // GET: Order
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(new Order());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(true)]
    public ActionResult Index(Order Order)
    {
        try
        {
            //OrderValidator validator = new OrderValidator();

            var upload = Request.Files["ticketFile"];
            if (ModelState.IsValid)//&& validator.Validate(Order).IsValid)
            {
                using (SaliceContext db = new SaliceContext())
                {
                    //bool isDetached = db.Entry(Order).State == EntityState.Detached;
                    //if (isDetached)
                    //  db.Orders.Attach(Order);
                    //db.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    //db.Entry(Order).State = EntityState.Added;
                    //db.Entry(Order).State = EntityState.Detached;
                    Order.OrderNumber = Guid.NewGuid();
                    db.Orders.Add(Order);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0 && (Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName) == ".pdf" || Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName) == ".docx"))
                    {
                        string path = Path.Combine(SaliceConstants.LOI, Order.id.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName));//.Replace("\\", "/");
                        upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
                        Order.File = path;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    db.Dispose();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("SaleConfirmed", "Order", new { orderNumber = Order.OrderNumber });
                //return "Order Saved your comfirmation key: " + Order.OrderNumber;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "An error happend"; return RedirectToAction("Error","Error");
            //return "An error happend";
        }
        return View(new Order());//"An error happend";

    }
    public ActionResult SaleConfirmed(Guid orderNumber)
    {
        try
        {

            ViewBag.Number = orderNumber;
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "An error happend"; return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
        }
        return View();
    }

}
```

entity

```
public class Order
{

    public Order()
    {
        using (SaliceContext db = new SaliceContext())
        {
            this.Ports = db.Ports.ToList();
            this.PaymentTypes = db.PaymentTypes.ToList();
            this.Products = db.Products.ToList();
            this.Grades = db.Grades.ToList();
            this.Packings = db.Packings.ToList();
            this.Inspections = db.Inspections.ToList();
            this.OrderNumber = new Guid();
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Guid OrderNumber { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("LastName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("Compay")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string Company { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("Position")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("Country")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("City")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("ContactNo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("PortName")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    //[MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string PortName { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("PortValue")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    //[MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string PortValue { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("PortId")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public int PortId { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("PortTypeId")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public int PortTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Port> Ports { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("PaymentTypeId")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public int PaymentTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PaymentType> PaymentTypes { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("Currency")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("ProductId")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("GradeId")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Grade> Grades { get; set;}
    [LocalDisplayName("PackingId")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //  ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public int PackingId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Packing> Packings { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("Packing")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    //[MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
    //          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string Packing { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("InspectionId")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public int InspectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Inspection> Inspections { get; set; }
    [LocalDisplayName("LOI")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
    //          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    //[MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLength",
    //          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string LOI { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Entire DB get duplicated"? All the records in all the tables?

Comment: can you show your `jquery` method also ?

Comment: yes all of records in all tables

Comment: jequery method of what

Comment: how to call this method ?

Comment: try to remove all dispose() methods within using(dbcontext) , and the double savechanges() , you also have two instances of the dbcontext at once, i bet this is the main part of the  problem

Comment: could it be somewhere db is not disposed?

Comment: your using((SaliceContext db = new SaliceContext()){}  shouldnt contain any disposing at all , using is handling that automagicaly for you

Comment: thanks Thorarins for you comment but how can i save the data i want to edit in that particular order without save changes

Comment: you only need to save once , its the same object Order

Comment: i did delete disposed items and savechanges was done once now all records of order get saved normally but other tables data's gets duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **technical problem** in my opinion are the following lines in your code:

```
Order.OrderNumber = Guid.NewGuid();
db.Orders.Add(Order);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Let's take a quick look at what is happening inside you controller:

- You get a new instance posted by the browser (via jquery in your case)

I assume you are posting **ALL** of the models properties (if you don't, this will set some properties to their default value etc after you make EF persist your changes). Note that at this time **EF does not know this object**, since it's state is not tracked by EF. It is only tracked after you add it to a DbSet or e.g. you load it from the database, our you **attach** it manually to the **Datacontext**. This is the main reason why you are reinserting the data - EF does not know the object and therefore does not know that it needs to be updated.

- Order.OrderNumber = Guid.NewGuid();

You are modifying the OrderNumber of the same order, which seems not correct (you would update it after saving would work correctly). I do not know if this is the primary key - if this i they case, I assume you only did this, because you got an SqlException when calling Savechanges (Primary Key Vialation)

- You add the submitted order to the DbSet (db.Orders.Add)
- You call SaveChanges() which persists the (new) order.

What you could do to solve the technical problem:

As your code example shows, you already wrestled with the object's **EntityState**.
As I already wrote above, the submitted Order is not tracked by EF. You could add the following (as it seems you already tried):

```
db.Orders.Attach(Order);
```

This will "re-add" the object to EF. What we are doing here is to manually tell EF that this object (with it's ID) was loaded from the database, but from a different DbContext (in the request that displayed the form/data). EF DbContext simply cannot "remember" the object accross multiple WebRequests (since the DbContext gets disposed between the requests).
But the question is, what EF does with the object's State. When Attaching an object, EF sets it's state to **Unchanged**, since it does not know which properties changed since it it was loaded.
You could change the entity's state to modified after  (thus telling EF "it changed, update all properties when calling SaveChanges()"):

context.Entry(Order).State = EntityState.Modified;

This will mark all properties as changed (without Navigationproperties).

So technically this should solve your problem - you can read more about this for exampe [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx), but I'd like to mention something else:

Usually (at least in my opinion) it's not a good idea to post the complete model model. The question is why?

- Security

You model my contain Foreign Key Properties which might be modified but should not be modified (imagine the user selecting something that he should not be able to select). This could be improved by using the BindAttribute which allows you to include/exclude properties. [See msdn on BindAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx)

- Flexibility

You have a lot of attributes on your model, which may only be required for UI concerns. Since you only have 1 model, you cannot display the same data differently in a different form (e.g. validation attributes etc...). For example in a Create usecase it may be optional to add an inforamtional message, but when updateing it it may be required.

It may be a good idea to start creating a separate **Viewmodel**, which only holds the data required for the page (and thus makes the usage of e.g. the BindAttribute obsolete).